# How create a unique ID based on conditions in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would like to get a new ID, no matter the format (in the example below 11,12,13...)
Based on the following condition:

Every time the **days** column value is greater then 1 and not null then current row and all following ones will get the same ID until a new value will meet the condition.
**Within the same email**

Below you can see the expected [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgtmH.png) (in the format of XX)

I thought about using two conditions with the following order between them

1. Every time the **days** column value is greater then 1 then all following rows will get the same ID until a new value will meet the condition.

2.AND When **lag (previous)** is equal to 0/1/null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an `EmailDate` column over which you're ordering (a `DATETIME` field, really), try something like this:

```
WITH 
    TableNameWithEmailDateIDs AS (
       SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY
                    Email DESC,
                    EmailDate
            ) AS EmailDateID
        FROM
            TableName
        ),

    IDs AS (
        SELECT 
            *,
            LEAD(EmailDateID, 1) OVER (
                ORDER BY 
                    Email, 
                    EmailDate
            ) AS LeadEmailDateID
        FROM
            (
            SELECT  
                *,
                -- REMOVE +10 if you don't want 11 to be starting ID
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    ORDER BY
                        Email DESC, 
                        EmailDate
                )+10 AS ID
            FROM
                TableNameWithEmailDateIDs
            WHERE
                Days > 1 
                OR Days IS NULL
            ) X
        )
        
SELECT
    COALESCE(TableName.EmailDate, IDs.EmailDate) AS EmailDate,
    IDs.Email,
    COALESCE(TableName.Days, IDs.Days) AS Days,
    IDs.ID
FROM
    IDs
    LEFT JOIN TableNameWithEmailDateIDs TableName
         ON IDs.Email = TableName.Email
        AND TableName.EmailDateID BETWEEN 
            IDs.EmailDateID
            AND IDs.LeadEmailDateID-1
ORDER BY
    ID DESC,
    TableName.EmailDate DESC
;
```

First, create a CTE that generates IDs for each distinct Email/Date combo (helpful for `LEFT JOIN` condition later). Then, create a CTE that generates IDs for rows that meet your condition (i.e. the important rows). Finally, `LEFT JOIN` your main table onto that CTE to fill in the "gaps", so to speak.

I suggest running each of the components of this query independently to fully understand what's going on.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, John.
I've replaced Email_date with stay_end (I assume this is what you meant).
I still have an issue that causes each row to be duplicated and to get a different ID.

Comment: Also I need to generate an ID even when the condition is not met like ID 11 & 14.
11 - Since this is the first row (looking button up)
14 - Since this is a new email.

Comment: @JonathanShahar Try again! I updated the SQL to fix what I think is your issue.